# How to find an objects that doesn't have some required properties from dictionary

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

1. object

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ball |
| 2 | pencil |

2. object_properties

| object_id | property_id | image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | path |
| 1 | 5 | path |
| 1 | 6 | path |
| 2 | 5 | path |

3. property

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | left |
| 5 | right |
| 6 | top |

All rows in the table property are required for object_properties.
In this case query should find the second object pencil, because it doesn't have the all properties.

I tried a query:

```
select b.* 
from objects b
left join object_properties p ON b.id = p.object_id
where property_id not in (select id from property)
```

But it's not working.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11eef6/3)

Expected result:

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | pencil |

Comment: consider what I wrote in my answer: repeated properties will give you wrong results if you only count the records: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b05ebcb2ca4f4b2e275b5eb80a339187

Comment: oups.. wrong like, this is the one I wanted to send: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=949251ba0d2360996711c59022cb376a

Comment: @jim-jones, yes, however we can use `count(distinct p.id)`

Comment: True. but keep in mind the overhead of `distinct`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f29bf96eacfa5bacf277e06a7a3d5cff the query plan speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to Gordon's query is to not only compare the number of records, but the records themselves:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT b.id,array_agg(p.property_id) prop
  FROM objects b
  LEFT JOIN object_properties p ON b.id = p.object_id
  GROUP BY b.id
)
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE prop <> (SELECT array_agg(id) FROM property);
```

If you just count the records, the query will filter out objects that e.g. contain `left` three times, which is most [`certainly invalid`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=207f336f77302e75336cf001b65d21f3).

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=180e526381312b947f30209cb7724bc9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to count the properties on each property and then `having` to filter down to the ones missing properties:

```
select o.id, o.name
from objects o left join
     object_properties op
     on o.id = op.object_id left join
     properties p
     on op.property_id = p.id
group by o.id, o.name
having count(p.id) <> (select count(*) from properties);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/57571/2) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that this returns both objets because the properties table has four rows not three.